# Who is starting xbindkeys?

Tags: 12.10, boot, shortcut-keys

When I restart my computer, `xbindkeys` is launched but it doesn't work right. If I kill it and then manually start it with `nohup xbindkeys`, it works fine. I think it'll work fine if I put it into my `.xsessionrc` file. But something else is already starting it when I boot, which interferes.

I recursively searched `/etc` for `xbindkeys` with no success.

Comment: Do you have any computers on a network?

Comment: Not sure what you mean. Many systems are on the same WiFi network as me. But there's only one user (me) of the system to which I'm referring, and it's always physical access to the machine. No SSHing or anything.

Comment: Ok. If you have file sharing on and there's a Ubuntu machine on the network with `xbindkeys`, then they might be running it at the same time as you. But I'm sure @Mik's solution will work.

Comment: I have a similar problem. When I start up, `xbindkeys -s` shows the correct list of commands, but they don't all work - I run `killal xbindkeys && xbindkeys`, and then they do work. Does your xbindkeys not work at all? Or do some commands work?

Comment: I have this exact same problem (2 years after last comment and on 15.10). Xbindkeys starts up automatically but my keys are not bound. If I kill it and start it again it works. I tried replacing the startup script with just `xbindkeys`, but it does the same thing.

Answer (score 8):

I have found that `xbindkeys` is automatically started if you have an `.xbindkeysrc` in your home folder or in a system folder such as `/etc`. Hence why it does not usually need to be added as a separate startup item once installed.

This is explained well in the file `/etc/X11/Xsession.d/98xbindkeys`, which is generated by any normal install from the Ubuntu package. Here is a snippet from the file, generated by running `cat /etc/X11/Xsession.d/98xbindkeys`:

```
This file is sourced by Xsession(5), not executed.

PROG="/usr/bin/xbindkeys"
NOAUTO="${HOME}/.xbindkeys.noauto"

This file autostarts xbindkeysrc if the user (or system) has a config
for it AND does NOT Have a .xbindkeys.noauto in his homedir.

[The rest of the file is a script]
```

So, the simple solution is to take note of the instructions and place a file named `.xbindkeys.noauto` in your home directory, and then `xbindkeys` won't start up with your x session, and you can place an alternative startup entry for it with your specific needs.

Comment: Great, I'll try this out. Do you have any ideas why the auto-started one might fail? Does it use a different $HOME or user or something?

Comment: @Espressofa I'm not sure why the auto-started one should fail; it seems to work in Precise (12.04), and `xbindkeys` is the same version in both Precise and Quantal.

Comment: It's weird -- the process is running but pressing my bound keys seems to have no effect. It's launched as `/usr/bin/xbindkeys /home/MY_USERNAME/.xbindkeysrc` -- which is the location is `xbindkeys` and of my config file. When I launch with just `xbindkeys` it works fine.

Comment: OK, so I have a .xbindkeys.noauto now and it doesn't autostart, as expected. I put `xbindkeys &` in my `.xsession` file. That process is running but it's not working. If I run in a terminal `kill xbindkeys; xbindkeys &` then it works.

Comment: @Espressofa Try adding `xbindkeys` as a user startup item instead of putting it in your `.xsessionrc`.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by that. If it helps, I use xmonad, not Unity.

Comment: @Espressofa Ah, I see. Perhaps you need to delay `xbindkeys` starting up by using `sleep` or something like that. It's difficult for me to diagnose what the issue could be, if you know you have nothing else interfering with `xbindkeys`.

Comment: I tried putting `sleep 3 && xbindkeys &` into my `.xsession` -- it still doesn't work.

Comment: @Espressofa If the `.xbindkeys.noauto` worked, `xbindkeys` shouldn't be starting up elsewhere, so again, I'm not sure what to suggest about why `xbindkeys` is still malfunctioning when launched from the xsession file. You could try launching `xbindkeys` in its own session with `setsid`, although there's no reason it should work. Try starting `xbindkeys` with `setsid xbindkeys` in your xsession file instead of `xbindkeys &`. I'm sorry that I can do little more than guess at the moment.

Comment: Yeah, it's very strange. The `.noauto` did work. It's definitely starting up from my `xsession` fine. I'll try playing around with `setsid`.

Answer (score 0):

I experienced the same problem when trying to get the touchpad on/off button working on my HP G60-530US laptop. When I login xbindkeys was running, killing xbindkeys & restarting xbindkeys would sometimes work. killing xbindkeys, running xbindkeys-config 'apply, save & exit' worked, but was pretty cumbersome.

Trying Mik's suggestion appeared to not work as I already had a 'xbindkeys' in my gnome-session-properties (gsp). I then remembered that just typing in the command in gsp often doesn't work; instead I click the 'browse' button and browsed to /usr/bin/xbindkeys to set the key. Logged out and logged backing and the mouse touchpad on/off buttons are now working properly.

HP G60-530US specific:

1. relevant bits of `~/.xbindkeysrc` (the rest of the file is default):

   ```
   #TouchpadOff - works
   "synclient TouchpadOff=1"
      0x1008ffb1

   #TouchpadOn - works
   "synclient TouchpadOff=2"
      0x1008ffb0
   ```
2. `.xbindkeys.noauto` is present in user home profile:

   ```
   ~/.xbindkeys.noauto
   ```
3. Enabled `/usr/bin/xbindkeys` was set using gnome-session-properties Startup Application Preferences. Important part (for me) was setting the command using the 'browse' button in the UI.

   ```
   Name: xbindkeys
   Command: /usr/bin/xbindkeys
   Comments: Touchpad on/off
   ```

Answer (score 0):

I had an issue with the same symptoms: xbindkeys appear to have been started, but no shortcut worked. After manually restarting xbindkeys from a shell it worked as expected.

My problem was that the commands tied to the shortcuts were dependent on my shell config (trying to start a Ruby command, but Ruby was loaded with asdf which is sourced in my .zshrc)

Solution was to replace the xbindkeys startup command from `xbindkeys` to `/usr/bin/zsh -c "xbindkeys"` and also move the asdf setup from `.zshrc` to `.zshenv`, since the latter is loaded even if no tty is present.

The startup command was editable from "Startup applications" in my Ubuntu 16.04.

Answer (score -1):

I dealt with this issue by running xbindkeys in terminal on startup!
Add Terminal=true in your .desktop file.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://askubuntu.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://askubuntu.com/help/privileges/comment).

Comment: @VolkerSiegel I believe this is an answer, the answerer says it solved the problem for him.

Comment: @VolkerSiegel It is indeed an answer and NOT a comment! I provided instructions (add Terminal=true to .desktop file that opens xbindkeys on startup, usually located under ~/.config/autostart) but due to the nature of the problem, I believe that it's a permission related bug in xbindkeys, I cannot be sure that it will work for everybody!